# FactoryGirl `factory define` pattern for a 'Factory' class which creates n number of Class types

Tags: ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I'm going to be as brief as possible, please assume that completely rewriting what im about to describe is imminent however `not on this sprint`

Given there is a factory class like (pseudo):

```
class AFactory

 ....
 def self.distribute_types(args)
   case args[:type]
     when A
        return ClassOfTypeA.new(args)
     when B
        return ClassOfTypeB.new(args)
     when C
        return ClassOfTypeC.new(args)
     else
        return ClassNamedSue(args)
   end 
 end
end
```

I need to write FactoryGirl traits for this "factory" class but i cant find examples of how to properly use /other/ factories which represent the class(es) which would be built, depending.

> edit: Please note, disregard the actual `AFactory` pattern - it is
>   known as suspect and will be properly redistributed along healthy
>   guidelines later on. Please do not spend time considering it's
>   wonky-ness and instead, focus on how to properly test this -- each
>   generated class instance, has a factory already dedicated to it, and I
>   would like to utilize those in this `AFactory` test.

How to include a factory within another factory - is the abject question i suppose.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to create a factory_girl factory which mimics the behavior of `AFactory` so that you can use the factory_girl factory in tests of classes that use `AFactory`? Or do you just want to test `AFactory`? If something else, please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no value in using FactoryGirl for this class.  Its only method is one that will generate an instance of a class if given the right arguments.

The more ideal approach would be to set up N cases - N representing the number of possible values `args[:type]` could take - and test that way.  You know what you're expecting when you feed the right type to this class, so there's little reason to include FactoryGirl for this test at all.

Here's a rough RSpec skeleton.  You're not testing anything other than the fact that your factory gave you the type you wanted (and also you'll want to test that it added the values you expected, but I leave that as an exercise for the reader).

```
describe AFactory do
  context 'when args[:type] is A' do
    let(:args) {
      {type: A}
    }

    it 'returns the right instance' do
      result = AFactory.distribute_types(args)
      # verify here
    end
  end

  context 'when args[:type] is B' do
    let(:args) {
      {type: B}
    }

    it 'returns the right instance' do
      result = AFactory.distribute_types(args)
      # verify here
    end
  end

  context 'when args[:type] is C' do
    let(:args) {
      {type: C}
    }

    it 'returns the right instance' do
      result = AFactory.distribute_types(args)
      # verify here
    end
  end

  context 'when args[:type] is any other value' do
    let(:args) {
      {type: 'foo bar baz bing boof'}
    }

    it 'returns the right instance' do
      result = AFactory.distribute_types(args)
      # verify here
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The reason for the Factory Girl integration is there is a substantial amount of shared information among these different classes (and required by the factory itself) - and each have at a minimum requirement of ~15+ initialization values. So factory girl was hoped to be leaned on in order to not create 100+ lines of "let" declarations within the rpsec file -- am i being unreasonably lazy with this goal? - Edit : I know that i can use other lets, to inject values within peer lets. Hoping to avoid that pattern as its spagetti

Comment: @BrandtSolovij: I think it's a bit from column A and a bit from Column B.  My understanding is that you wish to test `AFactory`.  If you do, you have no reason to include FactoryGirl *anywhere* near this, since you know which types you should expect when it's used.  If you intended to use `AFactory` in your tests to generate your models, then you should *exclusively* use FactoryGirl for that, since again, you already know which models you need and which state they need to be in.  So...be more lazy around this test and less lazy around the others, is what I'm thinking.

Comment: ok that line of reasoning makes sense to me. I'll take the path suggested (which also separates intent nicely) and will mark this answer as accepted if it pans out while keeping tests small (# of lines wise). thanks!

Comment: yep. Column A and Column B : Used the factories to `do their jobs` and checked that against some hash "lets" - marking this answer as accepted - i was overthinking the process - good stuff!